# How to access alertDialog information from new activity?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an app that asks the user to input Heads or Tails:

```
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Heads or Tails?")
                        .setSingleChoiceItems(coinOptions, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                //start coin toss
                                startPlay(which, coins);
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
                ad.show();
```

I'm just not sure exactly what it is passing to the new page? Is it an integer, 0 or 1 or something else? I am passing it as follows:

```
private void startPlay(int coinOption, int coins)
    {
        //start cointoss
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, CoinToss.class);
        playIntent.putExtra("bet", coinOption);
        playIntent.putExtra("coins", coins);
        this.startActivity(playIntent);
    }
```

and recieving it:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int totalCoins = extras.getInt("coins", -1);
        int bet = extras.getInt("bet", -1);
```

The information I want telling me heads or tails should be under the variable 'bet'.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: It will give the coinOptions position , i.e 0 or 1

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm new to this and I don't know what I'm doing. What value will be assigned to 'bet' if they click Heads, for example? 1 or 0, or something else? :)

Comment: Oh awesome thank you @King of Masses. I tried an if loop to check that but I must have had other bugs elsewhere, so didn't know what was breaking.

Comment: how you setted the data in coinOptions  array []

Comment: @KingofMasses sorry what do you mean?

Comment: coinOptions how your initializing and adding the coin Head / Tail options

Comment: @KingofMasses oh ok umm. I have to admit I don't fully understand exactly how I've set it up, I've never used an AlertDialog before so it was mainly trial and error. My entire programming knowledge is of basic Python from school...sorry :(. Can I do if(bet==0) to check if they entered heads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Implementation should be like this

```
  String [] coinOptions = {"Heads", "Tails"}; // adding your coin options
```

Your alert dailog should be like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Heads or Tails?")
                        .setSingleChoiceItems(coinOptions, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                //start coin toss

                                int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                                // Do something useful withe the position of the selected option
                                startPlay(selectedPosition , coins);
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
                ad.show();
```

Then your start play should be like this

```
private void startPlay(int coinOptionSelected, int coins)
    {
        //start cointoss
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, CoinToss.class);

          String selectedValue =null;
          if(coinOptionSelected != -1)     // if -1 means no option seletced do your rest handlings with else block
          {
                  selectedValue = coinOptions[coinOptionSelected];  //  if coinOptionSelected =1 then it will give Heads and if coinOptionSelected = 1 then it will give Tails
          }


        playIntent.putExtra("bet", selectedValue);
        playIntent.putExtra("coins", coins);  //  i dont know what this value you have
        this.startActivity(playIntent);
    }
```

Finally your receiving should be like this

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String selectedValue = extras.getString("bet");  // it will return Heads or Tails 
        int bet = extras.getInt("coins", -1);     // i dont know what this value you have
```

Comment: You're incredible, thank you so much! One last thing: I'm getting errors on the if(coinOptions != -1) statement. 'Operator '!=' can not be applied to Java.Lang.Charsequence' and also 'Incompatible types' (it's find a charsequence instead of a string) on the inside of that if statement?

Comment: Do I need to convert something to a string somewhere?